# What is the best java opts for running Berkeley DB JE?

Tags: jvm-arguments, jvm-crash, berkeley-db-je

I have a machine that inserts around 502,000,000 rows into a BDB JE. An example of a key and a value is:

```
juhnegferseS0004-47-19332   39694.290336
```

All of the keys and values are roughly of the same length. The JVM is started with the following parameters:

```
-Xmx9G -Xms9G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=1024m -server
```

But still, when it reaches ~50,000,000 rows, the JVM is "Killed" (I just get the message "Killed", don't know how/by whom it gests killed). I just guess it tries to run garbage collection and then it cannot free up enough memory or something. But, with that amount of -Xmx, I would guess it should not have any problems.

I use deferredWrites and the size of log files is set to 100MB. Switching to Base API from DPL did not make any difference.

I am using JDK 6.0 and SUSE x86_64 with 12GB of RAM. There are other processes that need the rest of the RAM, hence can't really allocate more than 9GB for this insertion task.

JVM:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Any tips for fixing this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single solution that is right for all situation. You will have to try different GC collectors to see which one performs best at the given situation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the JVM to die, and would recommend you trying a later (or perhaps even an earlier) JVM release (I'm talking a minor version e.g. JDK1.6.0_21 vs JDK1.6.0._22) in order to see if you can avoid triggering what is possibly a bug.

My other thought is that perhaps you're running into the Linux OOM killer issue (relating to memory overcommitting). See [this Serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/101916/turn-off-the-linux-oom-killer-by-default) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's an old question, recently I had the same problem. What I do to solve my problem, is using a gc log analyzer (which I found [GCeasy](http://gceasy.io) is awesome), and [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to have a deep sight of the problem.

And then I found that the class `com.sleepycat.je.tree.BIN` took almost the memory of JVM. In my case, the cache of JE is not so important (my app is an migration app). So I set up `CashMode.EVICT_BIN` to my databases.

What I mean is that the solution may not lay on the JVM options, but the app itself.